# C++ Exceptions not being caught on Raspberry Pi when compiled with gcc-4.8.5 but works with gcc-4.6.4

Tags: c++, gcc, arm, raspberry-pi2, crosstool-ng

Edit: this problem is not with my code, it has been tested on numerous other problems without issue.  This is a gcc cross compilation problem.

I am cross compiling a large C++ program with g++ on Ubuntu x64 to run on a Raspberry Pi 2.  When using gcc-4.6.4 everything seems to work.  When using gcc-4.8.5, exceptions seems to be leaking through and causing the program to abort.  I have tried a minimal example of exception catching using gcc-4.8.5 and the minimal case does seem to work properly. My actual program is far more complicated and it seems the exception catch is being lost somewhere.

Is there some g++ setting that I am missing that will improve exception handling?

I am compiling the toolchains with crosstools-ng 1.22

Edit:  This is essentially what the code is doing:

```
//error_function may be deeper in the stack
void error_function()
{
    throw std::runtime_error("This is an error");
}

try
{
    error_function();
}
catch (std::exception&)
{
   //Not being caught
}
```

Comment: Could it be that you are throwing an exception from a C++ callback called from a C library?

Comment: I'm relatively sure the problem is somewhere in your code. Extract a minimal example.

Comment: This code has been extensively tested on multiple platforms without issue.  The problem only occurs on gcc-4.8 armhf.  I haven't been able reproduce the problem with a minimal example, and the code is proprietary.

Comment: Start trimming your code until you get down to an example you can share. Very unlikely anyone will be able to help otherwise.

Comment: Trimming my code would not lead to a functional example.  I have added more of an example.  The problem seems to be because the catch is within a static library while the function is part of the application.  This seems to be a problem with the gcc configuration.  The problem is not with my software.

Comment: @John We don't need a functional example. We need an example where an exception should work but does not. Whether the code does anything useful or not is irrelevant to the question.

Comment: I did a complete rebuild of the 4.8.5 toolchain and it seems to work now.  I am still not sure what was wrong because I did not change any settings in the toolchain.

Comment: Is the static library compiled with the same compiler? With the same compiler options? I.e. both C++, same optimisation options and so forth? Is the function declared as extern "C"? It is possible that you are the victim of and... overenthusiastic ... optimisation.

Comment: Yes, it is compiled at the same time.  And yes, I set -O0 and everything works.  Debug build works now as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turning off optimization by setting -O0 seems to fix the problem.  This bug seems to be specific to gcc 4.8.5 ARMv6 hard float build.

Comment: You should bisect which *specific* `-f` flag is the problem using commands like `gcc -c -Q -O0 --help=optimizers`. In particular, I would try looking at options relating to unwind tables.

Comment: I am unfortunately not familiar with this level of compiler details.  I have created a paste-bin comparing gcc -c -Q -O0 --help=optimizers and gcc -c -Q -O3 --help=optimizers. Do you have any suggestions?  Testing each switch would take quite a long time. http://pastebin.com/fMV8RhTv

Comment: you don't have to test all the options at *once*, you can test half of them at a time, in `O(log(n))` time. That's why I said "bisect".

Comment: That assumes that a single option is causing the problem rather than a combination.  Which optimizations are most likely to cause the problem?